# Usage of "such that"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I am having issues with the wording of the following sentence:

> Overall our research shows an overreaching commonality, such that, social media has a significant impact on our physical well being and emotions.

I am unclear if the words "such that" are proper connectors between the two thoughts (should it be "in that"?). I have tried separating the two parts, but then the first sentence before the connector just sounds "empty".

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not at all sure about the use of 'commonality' for 'cause-and-effect relationship', before we get on to other issues ('in that', comma usage, spelling of well(-)being).

Comment: I think probably *overreaching* is a bad choice here - most likely you mean ***overarching***. As regards *such that*, I think it makes no sense at all here. Probably you mean ***in that*** (or perhaps ***insofar as*** or ***because***).

Comment: I think you're really aiming for a simple "for example". Or a simple "that is". A bit hard to tell, actually, what it is you're trying to say. Perhaps further context is in order. As far as *such that* is concerned, it means "to the extent that", "to the end that", "with the result that", and that of course makes no sense. As everyone so far, including yourself, agrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Such that" is out of place here; it is used to establish a circumstance from which the following statement is potentially or conceptually (but not directly) consequential. The "social media [have] a significant impact..." is proposed as a direct observation, not a potential or conceptual one.

"media" is a plural form of "medium", and the difference is especially in this statement (there are more than one forms of social media).

I agree with @Fumblefingers that ""overarching" is probably what you meant.

Try "throughout our research we observed an overarching common theme, which was that social media have a significant impact on our physical well-being and emotions."

Answer (score -1):

"that" is good enough to replace "such that", because "the part before" equals "the part" after "such that".